# How do I create a function in Python that can take a cube root of a fraction and return it in fraction form with a rationalized denominator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

So I am creating a program that can solve any cubic equation and give each root in it's exact form (not in decimal notation). I already have a program that can solve any cubic equation but it provides all three roots in decimal notation. Currently, I am reworking it so it can provide all three roots in their exact form, but I can't create a function that can take a cube root of a fraction that doesn't give the answer as a decimal.

This is the cube root function that gives the answer in decimal form

```
third = 1./3. #Cube root
def cubic_root(x):
        if x >= 0:
            return x**third
        else:
            return -(-x)**third
```

This is my attempt at recreating this function but with the ability to provide the user the cube root of a fraction while maintaining the answer in fraction form.

```
'''
Cubed Root Fraction Function
By Patrick Thomas
'''
#Program Infomation-------------------------------------------------------------
import time
import math
import fractions
time.sleep(0.5)
print('')
print('Cubed Root Fraction Function')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('A Patman Inc. Program')
time.sleep(0.5)

#While Loop---------------------------------------------------------------------
goAgain = True
while goAgain == True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('---------------------')
    radicalSign = '³\u221a'
    index = int(3.)
    radicand = input('Enter the radicand: ')
    
    
    if '/' in radicand:
        num,den = radicand.split('/')
        
        #Simplify
        def gcd(num,den):
            if int(den) == 0:
                return int(num)
            return gcd(int(den), int(num) % int(den))
        GCD = gcd(num,den)
        radicand_num = int(num) / GCD
        radicand_den = int(den) / GCD
    
    #Numerator------------------------------------------------------------------
        print('')
        
        #Postive Radicand-------------------------------------------------------
        if radicand_num > 0:
            cubeRoot_num = int(radicand_num ** (1./3.))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root_num in range(cubeRoot_num, 1, -1):
                factor_num = factor_root_num ** index
                if radicand_num % factor_num == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced_num = radicand_num // factor_num
                    if reduced_num == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        print(int(factor_root_num))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root_num), radicalSign, int(reduced_num))
                    break
                
            if not found: # irreducible radical
                print(radicalSign, int(radicand_num))
                    
        #Negative Radicand------------------------------------------------------
        elif radicand_num < 0:
            radicandNeg_num = radicand_num * -1
            cubeRoot_num = int(radicand_num ** (1./3.))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root_num in range(cubedRoot_num, 1, -1):
                factor_num = factor_root_num ** index
                if radicandNeg_num % factor_num == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced_num = radicandNeg_num // factor_num
                    if reduced_num == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        factor_rootNeg_num = factor_root_num * -1
                        print(int(factor_rootNeg_num))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root_num),'i', radicalSign, int(reduced_num))
                        break
            if not found: #irreducible radical
                if radicand_num == -1:
                    print('i')
                else:
                    radicandPos_num = radicand_num * -1
                    print('i',radicalSign, int(radicandPos_num))
                    
    #Denominator----------------------------------------------------------------
        print('')
        
        #Postive Radicand-------------------------------------------------------
        if radicand_den > 0:
            cubeRoot_den = (int(radicand_den ** (1./3.)))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root_den in range(cubeRoot_den, 1, -1):
                factor_den = factor_root_den ** index
                if radicand_den % factor_den == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced_den = radicand_den // factor_den
                    if reduced_den == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        print(int(factor_root_den))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root_den), radicalSign, int(reduced_den))
                    break
                
            if not found: # irreducible radical
                print(radicalSign,int(radicand_den))
                    
        #Negative Radicand------------------------------------------------------
        elif radicand_den < 0:
            radicandNeg_den = radicand_den * -1
            cubeRoot_den = (int(radicandNeg_den ** (1./3.)))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root_den in range(cubeRoot_den, 1, -1):
                factor_den = factor_root_den ** index
                if radicandNeg_den % factor_den == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced_den = radicandNeg_den // factor_den
                    if reduced_den == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        factor_rootNeg_den = factor_root_den * -1
                        print(int(factor_rootNeg_den))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root_den),'i', radicalSign, int(reduced_den))
                        break
            if not found: #irreducible radical
                if radicand_den == -1:
                    print('i')
                else:
                    radicandPos_den = radicand_den * -1
                    print('i',radicalSign, int(radicandPos_den))
    
    #Whole Number---------------------------------------------------------------
    else:
        radicand = int(radicand)
        print('')
        
        #Postive Radicand-------------------------------------------------------
        if radicand > 0:
            cubeRoot = int(radicand ** (1./3.))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root in range(cubeRoot, 1, -1):
                factor = factor_root ** 3.
                if radicand % factor == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced = radicand // factor
                    if reduced == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        print(int(factor_root))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root), radicalSign, int(reduced))
                    break
                
            if not found: # irreducible radical
                print(radicalSign, int(radicand))
                    
        #Negative Radicand------------------------------------------------------
        elif radicand < 0:
            radicandNeg = radicand * -1
            cubeRoot = int(radicand ** (1./3.))
            found = False
                
            for factor_root in range(root, 1, -1):
                factor = factor_root ** 3.
                if radicandNeg % factor == 0:
                    found = True
                    reduced = radicandNeg // factor
                    if reduced == 1: # radicand was a perfect root
                        factor_rootNeg = factor_root * -1
                        print(int(factor_rootNeg))
                    else: #radicand was not a perfect root but can be simplifed
                        print(int(factor_root),'i', radicalSign, int(reduced))
                        break
            if not found: #irreducible radical
                if radicand == -1:
                    print('i')
                else:
                    radicandPos = radicand * -1
                    print('i',radicalSign, int(radicandPos))
```

So as a side note, I am generally new to Python. I took a beginner's class for coding so that might help explain some things. If I could get help to make a function that can turn take a cube root of a fraction and provide the answer in fraction form with the denominator rationalized, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't anything built-in for this. You will either need to come up with an algorithm (hint: in order for the denominator to be rationalized after taking the cube root, what must be true of the denominator before? Given the numerator in that situation, what is the rule that tells you the integer and radical portions of the cube root?) or lean on a third-party library.

Comment: You can use the Vincent-Akritas (never Uspensky) algorithm to compute rational approximations  in continued fraction form to all (positive) real roots of any polynomial with integer coefficients (essentially, use fast root estimators to find integer intervals [n,n+1] possibly containing roots and recurse the algorithm for p(n+1/(1+x))*(1+x)^deg(p) -- polynomial shift and coefficient sequence inversion -- with appropriate book-keeping).

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, can the Vincent-Akritas algorithm compute rational approximations in fraction form with negative real roots or imaginary roots?

Comment: Negative roots easily, just replace p(x) with p(-x). Complex roots no, the algorithm relies too much on the integer coefficient sequence. The next best idea would be to approximate quadratic factors, but I have never seen that.

Answer (score 0):

## Main Question

> How do I create a function in Python that can take a cube root of a fraction and return it in fraction form with a rationalized denominator?

## Inexact Case

Cube roots of arbitrary fractions are typically irrational, so they would need to be approximated to get a rational result:

1. Convert the fraction to a float:  `f = float(somefrac)`
2. Take the cube root:  `r = f ** (1/3)`
3. Convert back to a fraction with [`limit_denominator()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator).

Here are the steps applied to an approximation of π:

```
>>> somefrac = Fraction(355, 113)
>>> f = float(somefrac)
>>> r = f ** (1/3)
>>> Fraction(r).limit_denominator(1000)
Fraction(1365, 932)
```

## Exact Case

If the starting fraction happens to be an exact cube, then you can get the exact fractional cube root by taking the roots of the numerator and denominator separately:

```
>>> f = Fraction(19683, 29791)
>>> Fraction(round(f.numerator ** (1/3)), round(f.denominator ** (1/3)))
Fraction(27, 31)
>>> Fraction(27, 31) ** 3
Fraction(19683, 29791)
```

## Bigger Question:  Rational Roots of Cubic Polynomials

One approach to finding exact rational roots of cubic equations is to apply the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  Here's a worked-out step-by-step procedure: https://www.storyofmathematics.com/rational-root-theorem/

For this, you don't need to compute cubic fractions (as requested in the title for this question).  Instead, use [*itertools.product()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) to generate possible solutions to the equation.

For example:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import product

def f(x):
    return 2*x**4 - 5*x**3 - 4*x**2 + 15*x - 6

constant_factors = [1, -1, 2, 2, 3, -3, 6, -6]
leading_coeff_factors = [1, -1, 2, -2]

roots = set()
for p, q in product(constant_factors, leading_coeff_factors):
    r = Fraction(p, q)
    if f(r) == 0:
        roots.add(r)
print(f'{roots=}')
```

This outputs:

```
roots={Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(2, 1)}
```

## Complete Solution

This can be made more efficient in some ways, but it is a good first pass:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import product
from math import lcm

def factors(n: int) -> int:
    'Positive and negative exact divisors of n'
    results = [1, -1]
    for d in range(2, abs(n)//2 + 1):
        if n % d == 0:
            results += [d, -d]
    results += [n, -n]
    return results

def eval_poly(coeffs, x):
    'Evaluate a polynomial a *x* given its coefficients'
    total = 0
    for c in coeffs:
        total *= x
        total += c
    return total

def cube_roots(*coeffs: int | Fraction) -> set[Fraction]:
    'Exact rational roots if they exist'
    # Coefficients arranged from highest power term down to the constant term
    s = lcm(*[c.denominator for c in coeffs])
    intcoeffs: list[int] = [(c * s).numerator for c in coeffs]
    candidate_roots = {Fraction(p, q)
        for p, q in product(factors(intcoeffs[-1]), factors(intcoeffs[0]))}
    return {r for r in candidate_roots if eval_poly(coeffs, r) == 0}
```

Example call:

```
# 2x⁴ - 5x³ - 4x² + 15x - 6
>>> cube_roots(2, -5, -4, 15, -6)) 
{Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(2, 1)}
```

Comment: I tried to run the program but it doesn't work